# Accepting POST form request from another site directly

Tags: angular, forms, http-post

Use case: User on site A submit the form with hidden input field which contains base64 encoded data. Action is url to site B which is angular 2 application.

It looks similar to this:

```
<form id="partner" method="POST" action="https://site-B/partner">
  <input type="hidden" name="pay-method" value="base64encodedvalue" />
</form>
```

Is there any chance to accept directly data comming from site A?

Comment: Just don't use `<form action="someurl">` in a SPA. Use code to post the form using `http.post()`

Comment: You can't read post data using frontend languages you need a serverside language to read post data

Comment: As @GünterZöchbauer said, I would suggest that you abandon `<form action="">` and create your own API services. Create a method to call in site B. Call it from site A with ajax calls (like the one mentioned by Gunter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was facing the same problem in my Angular 5 application, while I browsed through StackOverflow for possible workarounds, I couldn't get any.

This is how I got a solution.
You need to modify your form tag to the following:

```
<form #form ngNoForm
   id="partner" method="POST" 
   action="https://site-B/partner"
>
  <input type="hidden" name="pay-method" value="base64encodedvalue">
  <button type="submit" (click)="submitForm()" >Submit</button>
</form>
```

In your Component's TypeScript file,

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

export class YourComponentName {
    @ViewChild('form') form: ElementRef;

    submitForm() {
        this.form.nativeElement.submit();
    }
}
```

Let me know if you face any issues :)